# Raspberry's sound Bug with a bluetooth headphone

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, pulseaudio, headphones

everybody!
I'm trying to connect my raspberry pi 3 bluetooth to my headset. However the sound bug. It's kind of intermittently cutting off quite randomly, which makes it sound terrible.
I'm using the Raspberry 3's built-in bluetooth with Pulseaudio on Raspberry Pi OS V4.19.
How do I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the tag wikis you used. [tag:raspberry-pi3] says: "GENERAL RPI QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC.". Try raspberrypi.stackexchange.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the known issue. You might want to follow some of the issues that are open around this topic:

https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa/issues/60

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1552

https://github.com/balenalabs/balena-sound/issues/62